# How do I select a directory to save files in Pages

Tags: macos, pages

How do I select a directory to save files into?
In Pages I get the choice of Favorites or Recent Places?

Answer (score 2):

Use Save As

in the pop up window click on the down arrow to expand that window and choose where to save it.

Comment: Pro Tip: if you can see the folder you want on the desktop behind, drag it into the file picker & it will relocate to that folder.